# Eventbridge Rule target with input transform for list

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to do input transform from a list of objects. This is how the event detail:

```json
"detail": {
    "Id": 11111,
    "Name": "test",
    "Subjects": [
        {
            "Name": "Maths",
            "Mark": 30
        },
      {
            "Name": "English",
            "Mark": 40
        },
    ]
}
```

And the input path as follows:

```json
{
    "Id": "$.detail.Id",
    "Name": "$.detail.Name",
    "SubjectName":"$.detail.Subjects[*].Name",
    "SubjectMark":"$.detail.Subjecs[*].Mark"
}
```

Input template as given below:

```json
    {
       "Id":<Id>,
       "Name":<Name>
       "Subjects":[{
                    "Name": <SubjectName>,
                    "Mark":<SubjectMark>
                 }]
   }
```

But when I tried this with the EventBridge sandbox, only first item is transforming to the output.

```json
{
   "Id": 11111,
   "Name": "test",
   "Subjects": [{
                "Name": "Maths",
                "Mark": 30
               }]
}
```

Comment: Please add a code block with the expected transformed output.